# MediaPlayerLauncher on WP7 - how to resume previously playing media?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, media-player

I'm using a MediaPlayerLauncher to show movietrailers in my WP7 application, like this:

```
MediaPlayerLauncher mpl = new MediaPlayerLauncher();
mpl.Media = new Uri(trailerUrl, UriKind.Absolute);
mpl.Controls = MediaPlaybackControls.All;
mpl.Show();
```

This works just fine, except one thing: if the user is already listening to music in the background, and launch a trailer, the music is not resumed after the trailer is done playing (or if the user closes the video).

Does anyone know how i can resume the previously playing music/media, if even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Calling MediaPlayer.Resume() right after show() solves the issue:

```
mpl.Media = new Uri(trailerurl, UriKind.Absolute);
mpl.Controls = MediaPlaybackControls.All;
mpl.Show();

MediaPlayer.Resume();
```

However, i would still like to know how to resume radio and spotify!

Comment: Did you figure out how to resume Spotify? I'm dealing with the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Local media playing through XNA or a 'background audio agent'?

When you play media in WP7 / WP8, the OS audio context is taken, and the original context is lost. If the audio was launched from an external application, then you cannot resume at all. If the previous media was launched from within your application, then you could store the meta-data and re-play once your trailer is finished. The media would, of course, then begin playing from the start, rather than where the user left off. Unfortunately XNA does not allow you to seek within a given piece of media; however you can seek within an 'audio agent' instance of 'BackgroundAudioPlayer' by setting player.Position. It's also worth looking at the MediaHistory API:

```
var nowPlaying = Microsoft.Devices.MediaHistory.Instance.NowPlaying;
```

Comment: Talking of behalf of mr. Naumann, the media playing in the background would always be from the `BackgroundAudioAgent`. Let's say you want to watch a movie while using this app (while playing music). The music would stop, as it should, but it won't start up again. Since there is no event fired when the `MediaPlayerLauncher` is done showing video, it's hard to start the music playback again.