# Resuming spotify/radio after MediaPlayerLauncher's media is finished - WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, media-player, spotify, internet-radio

This question is related to another question i have asked:
[MediaPlayerLauncher on WP7 - how to resume previously playing media?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864557/mediaplayerlauncher-on-wp7-how-to-resume-previously-playing-media/11865530#11865530)

Quick overview: Users can view movietrailers in my WP7-app, using `MediaPlayerLauncher`.

I am able to resume "normal music" when my trailer is done, like you can see on my other asked question. However, neither radio nor spotify-music resumes. When navigating to the spotify application after a movietrailer is finished, the song that was playing has the pause-icon active (e.g it looks like it's playing), but the timer has stopped. Tapping the pause-icon has no effect (it doesnt switch to the play-icon at all). To start listening again i have to select a different song.

1. Do i have to resume radio/spotify-music after a trailer is done, or the user quits it, to get my app accepted in the Windows Phone Marketplace?
2. Independent of what the answer of #1 is, id like to know how to achieve this, if its possible

Answer (score 0):

Section 6.5 (6.5.1 and 6.5.3) in the Additional Certification Guidelines gives the answers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh184838(v=vs.92).

Normally you have to ask explicitly to play media if music is already playing (6.5.1). However, there is an exception which applies to you for 'non-interactive full motion video' (6.5.3), with extra the requirement that yes, you do have to resume the music afterwards.

Here are a couple of links that might help with resuming the original music after the video plays: http://www.governor.co.uk/news-plus-views/2011/2/16/resuming-background-music-in-wp7-applications and http://gdwp7dev.wordpress.com/2010/10/19/resume-the-users-music-after-mediaplay/